# HTTP HEAD Request in Javascript/Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to do a HTTP Head request solely using an XMLHTTPRequest in JavaScript?

My motivation is to conserve bandwidth.

If not, is it possible to fake it?

Comment: Yes, [check this...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Easy, just use the HEAD method, instead of GET or POST:

```
function UrlExists(url, callback)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url);
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
            callback(this.status != 404);
        }
    };
    http.send();
}
```

This is just a short example to show how to use the HEAD method. Production code may need more fine-grained callbacks for different result states (success, failure, timeout), and may use different [event handlers](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#event-handlers) (`onload`, `onerror` and `ontimeout` rather than `onreadystatechange`).

Comment: Thanks, sometimes the abstraction of a framework hides the underlying functionality!

Comment: Any idea how cross-browser this is? The jQuery documentation states "Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers." http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @outis: why this edit? I don't think stuff is getting better by this. I mean: the answer has served well for years, so why change it?

Comment: @doekman: Synchronous requests will block all JS-dependent tasks (Douglas Crockford once wrote that "[Synchronous programming](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/04/synchronous-v-asynchronous/) is disrespectful and should not be employed in applications which are used by people."). Think of all the people that unknowingly copied the example without thinking. For that reason, the answer has served poorly for years. The update both shows how to use asynchronous requests and makes explicit the fact that the example shouldn't be copied verbatim.

Comment: @outis: I applaud your async change (and I don't question that). I didn't even see that change. I only saw you change the semantics/name of the function. I saw no reason for that (and I liked my simple, yet useful function), so I changed that back if you don't mind :-)

Comment: I applaud the fact that this answer is jQuery free. Even the simplest of JS questions on SO is almost always answered with a jQ solution.

Comment: Any chance that b.c. this is just a HEAD request, one can go cross-domain?

Comment: Note that this works OK when the page is behind a server - I found that the readyState is always 0 when loading the page straight off a file.

Comment: Then you can use `getAllResponseHeaders` or `getResponseHeader("header-name")` on the `this` object (the XHR object) to get the actual headers received, as @adam mentioned.

Comment: Checking for status code `404` only doesn't indicate that the URL exists.  For example, it's perfectly valid to use `403` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The more modern approach is to use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) which replaced `XMLHttpRequest`.

e.g. (within an `async` function)

```
const url = "https://example.com";
const response = await fetch(url, { method: "HEAD" });
console.log(`Got status: ${response.status}`);
```

Answer (score -6):

An XMLHTTPRequest object should have

```
getAllResponseHeaders();
getResponseHeader("header-name")
```

defined on it

Comment: Downvote: The answer seems to confuse the [HTTP HEAD method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) with [HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers).