# JavaScript/jQuery check broken links

Tags: javascript, jquery, broken-links

I developed a small Javascript/jQuery program to access a collection of pdf files for internal use. And I wanted to have the information div of a pdf file highlighted if the file actually exist.

Is there a way to programmatically determine if a link to a file is broken? If so, How?

Any guide or suggestion is appropriated.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If the files are on the same domain, then you can use AJAX to test for their existence as [Alex Sexton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591401/javascript-jquery-check-broken-links/1591449#1591449) said; **however, you should not use the `GET` method, just `HEAD`** and then check the HTTP status for the expect value (200, or just less than 400).

Here's a simple method provided from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333634/http-head-request-in-javascript-ajax):

```
function urlExists(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      callback(xhr.status < 400);
    }
  };
  xhr.open('HEAD', url);
  xhr.send();
}

urlExists(someUrl, function(exists) {
    console.log('"%s" exists?', someUrl, exists);
});
```

Comment: I wish I knew how to implement this for the OP's question. Anyone?

Comment: I get an error with this code: "Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: Please look up JavaScript's same origin policy.

Comment: Only if the server allows it.  It can be enabled/disabled.

Comment: Is there way to check foreign domains links from javascript? I want only validity it, without get any content... No?

Comment: JavaScript can only make requests to the same domain that the page is hosted on or hosts that specifically allow the host that your script is hosted from or hosts that allow all hosts (via Access-Control-Allow-Origin). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS for specifics.

Comment: `Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://www.google.com/'.`

Comment: Are you making the request from google.com?  If not, look up CORS.

Comment: One problem is that synchronous Ajax on main thread will be impossible in the future.  How solve for that?

Comment: The http://binarykitten.com/js/88-jquery-plugin-ajax-head-request.html URL embedded in the question is now a 404 and I removed the hyperlink.

Comment: @rob check my answer

Comment: This returns true if CORs blocks the call.

Answer (score 3):

Issue is that JavaScript has the same origin policy so you can not grab content from another domain. This won't change by upvoting it (wondering about the 17 votes).
I think you need it for external links, so it is impossible just with .js ...

Answer (score 1):

If the files are not on an external website, you could try making an ajax request for each file. If it comes back as a failure, then you know it doesn't exist, otherwise, if it completes and/or takes longer than a given threshold to return, you can guess that it exists. It's not always perfect, but generally 'filenotfound' requests are quick.

```
var threshold   = 500,
    successFunc = function(){ console.log('It exists!'); };

var myXHR = $.ajax({
  url: $('#checkme').attr('href'),
  type: 'text',
  method: 'get',
  error: function() {
    console.log('file does not exist');
  },
  success: successFunc
});

setTimeout(function(){
  myXHR.abort();
  successFunc();
}, threshold);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `$.ajax` to it. If file does not exist you will get 404 error and then you can do whatever you need (UI-wise) in the error callback. It's up to you how to trigger the request (timer?) Of course if you also have ability to do some server-side coding you can do a single AJAX request - scan the directory and then return results as say JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Like Sebastian says it is not possible due to the same origin policy. If the site can be published (temporarily) on a public domain you could use one of the link checker services out there. I am behind [checkerr.org](http://checkerr.org)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, because of JavaScript's same origin policy, simply using the function from the accepted answer does not work. A workaround to this is to use a proxy server. You don't have to use your own proxy for this, you can use this service for example: https://cors-escape.herokuapp.com (code [here](https://github.com/shalvah/cors-escape)).

The code looks like this:

```
var proxyUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";

function urlExists(url, callback) {
  var sameOriginURL = proxyUrl + url;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      callback(xhr.status < 400);
    }
  };
  xhr.open('HEAD', sameOriginURL);
  xhr.send();
}

urlExists(someUrl, function(exists) {
  console.log('"%s" exists?', someUrl, exists);
});
```