# Manipulate linked files on the HTML dynamically

Tags: java, php, jquery, archive, webarchive

I have a backup website. Something like [Wayback machine](http://archive.org/web/web.php0). When I return the contents of the HTML, obviously, the linked documents (like images, javascript files, css files, etc.) are loaded from the original web server (instead of my server). Now I want to replace those links so that they are loaded from my server. I have two approaches to take:

1. Do it server-side using Java or PHP. I can use both Java and PHP to do this. For instance in Java, I could use jSoup to parse the HTML and replace the links.
2. Do it client-side using jQuery.

Using 2nd method means I don't have to add load on my server to parse the HTML but I think, as soon as the page is being loaded, the files will begin to download from the original server and the user's bandwidth would be wasted.

On the other hand, if I could somehow determine whether the image has been successfully downloaded, I could skip the download from my server and let the user use the file downloaded from the original server.

What is your suggestion for this?

### Update

About relative and absolute links I should do some clarifications. The links on my service are stored as absolute paths. However, the HTML documents may have both types of links. What I need to do is:

- Convert `http://stackoverflow.com/images/image.png` to `http://mysite.com/view/content?url=http://stackoverflow.com/images/image.png`
- Convert `/images/image.png` (on the `http://stackoverflow.com`) to `http://mysite.com/view/content?url=http://stackoverflow.com/images/image.png`

In short, the relative links on the HTML should be converted to absolute links and then be sent to my website as the `URL` argument.

Comment: Are the links relative or hardcoded to the url?

Comment: Both. Documents are crawled from web. Websites could have used anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the links are relative, you could add a `<base>` tag with jQuery.

```
$(function () {
    var base = $("<base>", {
        href: "http://www.your-new-website.com/"
    });
    $("head").append(base);
});
```

**UPDATED**

jQuery will not be the best solution because you will make 2 calls for every item...one for the initial load from the original server and one for the second load from the new server as jQuery changes the `img` and `css` links.  Nonetheless, this should work.

```
function replaceDomain(href) {
    var originalDomain = document.domain;
    var newDomain = "mysite.com/view/content?url=http://" + originalDomain;
    if (href.indexOf(originalDomain) == -1) href = "http://" + originalDomain + href;
    return href.replace(originalDomain, newDomain);
}
$(function () {
    //convert links
    $('a').each(function () {
        $(this).attr("href", replaceDomain($(this).attr("href")));
    });

    //convert imgs
    $('img').each(function () {
        $(this).attr("src", replaceDomain($(this).attr("src")));
    });

    //convert css links
    $('link').each(function () {
        $(this).attr("href", replaceDomain($(this).attr("href")));
    });
});
```

Comment: How didn't I think about this? :D Let me test this and get back to you.

Comment: It will only work if the website has relative links..hardcoded urls will not respect the `base href`

Comment: Please read the update of my question. This may work but needs some work. What do you suggest for this?

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way I could determine whether the document has been downloaded? In that case, I could skip the second request in some cases.

Comment: Maybe check url for 404 before replacing?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591401/javascript-jquery-check-broken-links