# How to show the object in an AngularJS ng-repeat loop, only if its nested image exists?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-show

My AngulaJS driven frontend gets the data from a local `JSON` file and will later switch to an API. The data is a list of `Project` objects with nested lists of `Image` objects. I'm displaying this data in a loop:

```
<div id="projects" ng-app="portfolio">
    <div id="projectsList" ng-controller="ProjectsListController as projectsList">
        <div class="projectItem" ng-repeat="projectItem in projectsList.projectsListData._embedded.projects">
            <div class="project-image">
                <img
                    ng-src="{{projectItem._embedded.images[0].src}}"
                    title="{{projectItem.title}} - {{projectItem._embedded.images[0].title}}"
                    alt="{{projectItem.title}} - {{projectItem._embedded.images[0].title}}"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But sometimes the image `src` is invalid (error `404`). It would be better to skip such projects, where the first image (`images[0]`) cannot be found. How to make the script skip the irrelevant objects?

---

**EDIT**

I've already got three answers, but the solutions don't work and I want to explain the problem exactly:

The `src` property of the images is alwys set. It's *not* the problem. That means, that checking if it's set or not (like `ng-show="projectItem._embedded.images[0].src != ''"` or `ng-if="{{projectItem._embedded.images[0].src}}"`) will *not* work -- cannot work.

It doesn't work -- the `src` property is set. It's wrong (will cuase the `404` error), but it's set and `projectItem._embedded.images[0].src != ''` will return `true` for the "irrelevant" objects as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've come up with an approach for this. Check if its useful for you. Demo : http://jsbin.com/kedirofako/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hacky way of making this work:

To avoid loading images when they throw `404` error or when the images are invalid,

This must be inside your controller. This function checks whether the image URL is valid/invalid.

```
$scope.imageExists = function(image, object, index) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      object[index] = true;
      $scope.$apply();
    }; 
    img.onerror = function() {
      return false;
    };
    img.src = image;
 };
```

Now in View:

I'm initiating an object called `img={};` in the `ng-repeat`.

Then initializing the value for that index in `ng-repeat` to `$scope.imageExists` function. Inside that function, on success of that image load, am setting `img[index]= true`.

```
<div ng-repeat="image in images" ng-init="img = {}">
   <img ng-src="{{image}}" ng-init="img[$index] = imageExists(image, img, $index)" ng-show="img[$index]">
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kedirofako/1/edit?html,js,output)**

So applying it to your code:

```
<div id="projects" ng-app="portfolio">
    <div id="projectsList" ng-controller="ProjectsListController as projectsList">
        <div class="projectItem" ng-repeat="projectItem in projectsList.projectsListData._embedded.projects"  ng-init="img = {}">
            <div class="project-image" ng-init="img[$index] = imageExists(projectItem._embedded.images[0].src, img, $index)" ng-show="img[$index]">
                <img
                    ng-src="{{projectItem._embedded.images[0].src}}"
                    title="{{projectItem.title}} - {{projectItem._embedded.images[0].title}}"
                    alt="{{projectItem.title}} - {{projectItem._embedded.images[0].title}}"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Place the `$scope.imageExists` code from above to your controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

```
<div class="projectItem" ng-repeat="projectItem in projectsList.projectsListData._embedded.projects" ng-if="{{projectItem._embedded.images[0].src}}">
            <div class="project-image">
                <img
                    ng-src="{{projectItem._embedded.images[0].src}}"
                    title="{{projectItem.title}} - {{projectItem._embedded.images[0].title}}"
                    alt="{{projectItem.title}} - {{projectItem._embedded.images[0].title}}"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Or you can also use ng-show/ng-hide which just doesn't show the element but would be present in DOM.

But be careful when you use ng-if as it creates its own scope.

**EDIT:** If the url is already set then one way is to test if the url exists using this method (or anything like this) [JavaScript/jQuery check broken links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591401/javascript-jquery-check-broken-links) , and
 `ng-if="UrlExists(projectItem._embedded.images[0].src)"`

Comment: It doesn't work -- the `src` property is set. It's wrong (will cuase the `404` error), but it's set and `projectItem._embedded.images[0].src != ''` will return `true` for the "irrelevant" objects as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div class="project-image" ng-if="projectItem._embedded.images[0].src != ''">
            <img
                ng-src="{{projectItem._embedded.images[0].src}}"
                title="{{projectItem.title}} - {{projectItem._embedded.images[0].title}}"
                alt="{{projectItem.title}} - {{projectItem._embedded.images[0].title}}"
            />
        </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work -- the `src` property is set. It's wrong (will cuase the `404` error), but it's set and `projectItem._embedded.images[0].src != ''` will return `true` for the "irrelevant" objects as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own image directive:

```
<my-image src="http://someimageurl"></my-image>
```

If the image exists, the directive will insert the image into the DOM.  If it does not, then you can ignore it, or insert a message.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('myImage', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace:true,
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      var image = new Image();
      image.onload = function() {
         element.append(image);
      }
      image.onerror = function() {
         element.html('Something went wrong or the image does not exist...');
      }
      image.src = attr.src;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <my-image src="https://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
  
  <my-image src="https://server/images/doesnotexist.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works for the `img` tag, bun in my case I want to enable/disable the whole container wrapping the image.