# If webpage exsits load, if not load .mht

Tags: html, mhtml

Working in HTML/SCSS/JQUERY.

Want to link to a webpage but if it's a broken link that it will load the saved `.mht` version.

Comment: not apart from an <a> tag, I can't even get the .mht to load in browser, it just goes to download.

Answer (score 0):

Another user provided this code in other thread of this forum to chek if a link is broken ([JavaScript/jQuery check broken links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591401/javascript-jquery-check-broken-links))

```
function urlExists(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      callback(xhr.status < 400);
    }
  };
  xhr.open('HEAD', url);
  xhr.send();
}

  urlExists(someUrl, function(exists) {
  console.log('"%s" exists?', someUrl, exists);
```