# Javascript: How can I check to see if url to fire exists before firing it?

Tags: javascript, click

I am getting urls from a feed that I assign to list of buttons, some of the urls produce 404s when clicked on said buttons. Is there a way to check if the landing page exists first before I fire it?

Some of these urls have tracking pixels in them to know when they are clicked so I wouldn't want to fire it in an iframe or a similar solution as it would possibly track twice to test if it exist first before it fires.

Is this even possible? The domains will not be the same and I can't use jQuery.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10926978/4244009

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript/jQuery check broken links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591401/javascript-jquery-check-broken-links)

Comment: Sorry I should add that the domains will not be the same in which the above suggestions require.

Comment: Unfortunately, the AJAX same-origin rule will usually prevent you from doing this in Javascript. Can you run a script on the server to do the checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test an url you must access it. So, without an external service, you can't test them beforehand.

W3C provides a link checker: https://validator.w3.org/checklink
"The program can be used either as a command line tool or as a CGI script."
Maybe you can use it to test an url and, after, create or not your button.

I don't know if there is a limit for this service, so check the documentation! 
http://search.cpan.org/dist/W3C-LinkChecker/bin/checklink.pod