# How to handle error if iframe [src] gives 404 Error using angular 5

Tags: iframe, angular5, http-status-code-404

I use an iframe to display several documents in an iframe with dynamic src. Some of them exist, but some others do not and I receive a 404 Error.
Please find my code below:

```
<iframe class="e2e-iframe-trusted-src" style="width: 100%" height="1000" 
[src]="trustedUrl" (load)="oniFrameLoad($event)"></iframe>
```

Please let me know how I can handle the 404 error (or even better know beforehand that the src path does not exist and the document is not displayable).

Comment: There is an issue associated to it. As now a day due to security reasons cross-origin flags are set. We can't directly do an XHR call as well to check the URL.
If you are using link form your own side then I would suggest to you go for solution mentioned in below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591401/javascript-jquery-check-broken-links