# Cross Domain 'Http Head' Request

Tags: browser, cross-domain

Do Browsers allow cross domain 'Head' Request?

Comment: What is a cross domain 'Head' Request?

Comment: Do browsers allow to make 'head' ajax request on a different domain!!

Comment: This link may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333634/http-head-request-in-javascript-ajax

Comment: Question 333634 deals with head requests but not cross domain requests.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. Cross-domain requests (e.g., JSONP, image loads) must load the whole resource with a `GET`.

If bandwidth is an issue but latency is not, you can create a server-side script on the same domain to proxy the `HEAD` request.