# Know if a picture is CORS-enabled without downloading it

Tags: javascript, canvas, cors

I'm interested in loading a picture in a canvas to read the pixel values. This requires the image to be CORS-enabled. Given an image URL, it is possible to know if the corresponding image is CORS-enabled without having to download it?

Comment: Have you tried a **HEAD** HTTP request via `XMLHttpRequest`? That way you only download the headers, not the actual image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No code solution is http://www.corsproxy.com/ the other is the one mentioned above. Just make a short HEAD request with the method described here: [HTTP HEAD Request in Javascript/Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333634/http-head-request-in-javascript-ajax) and check the responseHeaders.