# XHR request only headers

Tags: javascript, header, xmlhttprequest

is it possible to use XHR to get only the file's headers without downloading the file itself?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333634/http-head-request-in-javascript-ajax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the http HEAD method instead of GET method.

```
xhr.open("HEAD", url, async)
```