# Qt/QML. A way to learn image size without load

Tags: image, qt, qml

I have a set of images (url addresses). Some of them are of acceptable size, but some are too big. When I load it, the app crashes because of big images.

Is there a way to get the image size (megabytes) before loading it? This way I can remove large images from the list, and avoid loading them.

Comment: If you have access to server, maybe you could resize image to maximum allowed size at image upload and then you would have all images same size with, let's say, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819524/a-very-good-php-image-resize-script-suggestion. I used similar way in my project from year and half ago and has been working since then perfectly. I think (my humble opinion) that this is something client should not worry about. It is server's task to prepare "valid" data for client.

Comment: yes, you are right. An idea to remove large images from load list is a temporary crutch. In the future it will in the way you advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server where the images are located supports it, you can issue a `HEAD` request. This can be done in Qt using e.g. [QNetworkAccessManager::head](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#head).

It should also be possible in QML/Javascript, see [HTTP HEAD Request in Javascript/Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333634/http-head-request-in-javascript-ajax).

Comment: I wouldn't like to do it in Qt/c++ , because there is a cute implementation with plain QML :-) But thanks for reply, I'll try it!