# How to write java script that can set a variable if a particular third party java script has executed?

Tags: javascript, html, web

My webpage needs a third party script, and that url is banned in some locations, I want to know, If there is any way I could find out whether the third script  executed or not ?

Comment: `if (typeof <any function/object/... from the external script> !== "undefined") { ... }`

Comment: @Andreas - Why comment but not an answer ?

Comment: @Andreas but if the external script changes than function and object will change,in that case i have to keep record of them

Comment: @Andreas can I map it with the source location ?

Comment: If the function/object... you're testing against gets changed or removed than you will have to adjust your script accordingly. If the url is blocked you could also try loading the url with a [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). If this fails (error, status, status code, response text, ...) you could assume that the external script also failed to load.

Comment: @Andreas but it may slow down the web page loading if the script is big, for the users where url is accessible , Is there any method that can just ping the url and tell the response whether host  is reachable or not ? I can safely assume that if url is accessible than definitely third party java script will load

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333634/http-head-request-in-javascript-ajax