# Ping url with getting cached version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser-cache

I've got a script which displays an alert showing whether an image has been located or not, but I'm looking to prevent a false positive from the image being cached by the browser.

Usually I add something like  `"http://192.168.8.1/images/ping2.jpg"+"?rand="+randomNum;` to add a random number but I'm finding this is not working with this implementation.

```
<script> function pingImage(URL) {
    var tester=new Image();
    tester.onload=imageFound;
    tester.onerror=imageNotFound;
    tester.src=URL;
}

function imageFound() {
    alert('That image is found and loaded');
}

function imageNotFound() {
    alert('That image was not found.');
}

pingImage("http://192.168.8.1/images/ping2.jpg");

</script>
```

Comment: The cachebuster URL parameter definitely should work. The cache has to include the URL parameters.

Comment: Try [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/333657/266535). Does that work for you?