# How to protect a client side JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, variables, browser, client-side

Using the following function to check the existence of a given URL. The code is executed on the client side (browser), **is there a way (if at all possible) to protect the `url` variable from being altered with the browser debugger while keeping the function on the client side?**

Note that the `url` variable is generated by the server and set on the JS script (client side)

```
function UrlExists(url, callback)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url);
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
            callback(this.status != 404);
        }
    };
    http.send();
}
```

Function [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333634/http-head-request-in-javascript-ajax).

Answer (score 2):

No.

The code runs in the browser. The browser is completely under the control of the user. JavaScript is pretty easy to deobfuscate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to protect the values of variables from being edited or looked at by the console or such, you should look at scoping through IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

> Since the anonymous function within our IIFE is a function expression
>   and is not being assigned to a global variable, no global property is
>   being created, and all of the properties created inside of the
>   function expression are scoped locally to the expression itself.

This way, any variable you declare and set within this function can not be accessed simply through the window object that your console works in.

If you are looking for some extra security and encrytion, search for `JavaScript Obfuscator`

Comment: nice answer i just upvoted it, but is not that just a trick? i mean if we edit the code of the js engine we could in theory alter those variable? don't we?

Comment: Yes, the above approach is just a way around.

Answer (score 0):

While different methods to obfuscate js exist like https://obfuscator.io this does not guarantee any true additional security (but this can make the code not easy to read/debug).

Any thing that is handled on the client side (on the browser [js engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine)), can be altered on the client side with the debugger or with other methods.