# Opening a JSON response in JavaScript and reroute it to a file if it is too large to handle

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm looking for a way to do a bit of conditional logic inside JS code when displaying a potentially large response (more than a couple of megabytes) in browser.

For the sake of the example, let's say I'm using the `Axios` library and calling its `.post()` method. Note that I don't really think the specific library should matter here - I'm basically looking for a general purpose answer, which should work with plain JS, as well!

Let's assume that a given request can cause a JSON response of an arbitrary size. How can I decide how I want to process it on the client side so it doesn't bring the browser process down, if it happens to be larger than a certain arbitrary limit?

In other words, I would only like to load and process responses up to, say, 5 MB in size. Any larger response should instead be downloaded to a file via normal browser mechanism (including UI dialog, if the browser is configured to ask the user before downloading).

When this part is done, my JS code would then tell the user what to do with the file in order to achieve the desired result (one that would normally happen automatically given a smaller response).

I already know I can make this decision programmatically by inspecting the `Content-Length` header of the response to determine if it breaks my arbitrary limit or not. The problem is, I don't know what to do when this happens. How do I redirect such a response to a file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP HEAD Request in Javascript/Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333634/http-head-request-in-javascript-ajax)

Comment: Very confused on what you are asking. You are talking about posting up a file and you are talking about processing it on the client side? What exactly are you doing? You are uploading a file and you do not want them to upload it? Or you are posting something and the content coming back is too big to handle?

Comment: If it's an array you can simply use `.length()` to find out how large it is. If it's small, display the results in a table. If not, upload it to the server and use another API to browse it.

Comment: @epascarello: It's the latter. I'm just making a small POST request, and have to be prepared to receive a response that's potentially too large to handle in the normal UI logic. For example, blindly loading a 50 MB JSON response has actually brought the browser to its knees on more than one occasion, because it balloons and freezes the UI for an unacceptable amount of time.

Comment: So you either check the length before you parse it OR you build the backend to throw a custom error. IF you are using axios you will have to do a custom transform response so it does not start to do the parsing when it sees it is JSON.

Comment: @tevemadar: I don't think so, no. It's not really a simple file, but rather a dynamically generated response by the server, which involves a lot of processing - i.e. it's an expensive call! As such, it's not feasible to make two of them (one using HEAD and the second using POST), as the server would need to be aware of this protocol and not rerun the expensive logic in this case. And unfortunately, it isn't aware of this.

Comment: @epascarello: It's not an error as far as the back-end is concerned. It's a valid response. It's just larger than the client can process in browser without causing problems with UI blocking and the CPU/RAM usage ballooning. The threshold is relatively simple to determine. What I'm looking for is a way to programmatically decide whether a certain AJAX response will be processed inline or redirected to the browser's default download UI.

Comment: FWIW: I'm currently investigating this path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post

Comment: I am going off details in your question so assumed large file was not going to be processed and not mean it would be dowloaded. So my theory of an error was thinking you could not display it. It is simple to determine, but the issue is there is no simple way to do this. There are solutions with converting it to a blob to download, but will that lock up your browser? :)

Comment: Yes, I wanted to suggest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/create-and-save-a-file-with-javascript, but mostly the same. You could start a `fetch()`, then get [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), check the headers for size, and then either call `json()` and handle it in place, or `blob()` and go with the save-to-disk thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rudimentary implementation of the comment, deciding what to do on the client-side, based on filesize:

```js
async function doThing() {
  const response = await fetch("https://object.cscs.ch/v1/AUTH_7e4157014a3d4c1f8ffe270b57008fd4/ewb-c3300430-fc01-44cd-941d-3be963a065f9?stats&format=json");
  const size = parseInt(response.headers.get("Content-Length"));
  const thing = document.getElementById("thing");
  if (size <= document.getElementById("limit").valueAsNumber) {
    const object = await response.json();
    thing.innerText = JSON.stringify(object, null, 4);
  } else {
    thing.innerText = "Too large, saved instead - doesn't work here on SO";
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = "something.json";
    a.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="limit" value="3000"><button onclick="doThing()">Clicky</button><br>
<pre id="thing"></pre>
```

If you leave it with the default limit, the file will show (it's some 2544 bytes). If you lower the limit below that, it will try to do a download (which won't succeed here because of sandbox settings, but works at https://jsfiddle.net/tevemadar/mq01p5x3/ for example).

Comment: Thank you! The combination of blob() and createObjectURL() was exactly what I needed!